# Actualizar funcion AJAX con nuevo valor desde función

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, leaflet

tengo el siguiente problema a ver si alguien me podria ayudar. Estoy tratando de hacer un seguimiento de aeronaves, para ello ocupo una función AJAX que recibe los datos de acuerdo al id, si ingreso los id de forma manual funciona sin problemas. El detalle es que al traer el id ingresando el valor desde un input en html, el primer valor lo muestra bien y actualiza al objeto, pero si ingreso un nuevo valor, igual lo trae pero sigue mostrando el valor anterior, es decir, si busco el id "001" y despues el "002", no se borra el id "001" y sigue mostrando ese objeto junto con el "002". La pregunta aqui es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se borre los datos que ingrese anteriormente para buscar nuevos ids?

Adjunto codigo de AJAX que obtiene los datos de la consulta y me actualiza el marcador en cuestión:

```js
function searchAero(id) {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/getIds/" + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                for (var key in response.coordenadas) {
                    var datosDB = [response.coordenadas[key].Ima_remitente, response.coordenadas[key].Latitud, response.coordenadas[key].Longitud];
                }
                marker.setLatLng([datosDB[1], datosDB[2]]).update();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log('No se pueden obtener las coordenadas');
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
};
```

Función para validar si un campo esta vacio, si no lo esta, solo llama a la función anterior y obtiene el valor del input "inputId":

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonId").click(function () {
        if (validaCampo()) {
            searchAero($("#inputId").val());
        }
    })
})
```

De antemano agradezco cualquier solución o sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como la función inicializa el `setInterval`, lo que ocurre es que la primera vez se establece el valor dado como dato a procesar con `$.ajax`, y se termina repitiendo el proceso cada segundo. Lo que tendrías que hacer es finalizar el `setInterval` con `clearInterval` antes de volver a llamar a la función con el nuevo dato.

```
//En el ámbito global
let interval;

//En la función
interval = setInterval(/* instrucciones */);

//En la llamada a la función
clearInterval(interval);
//Aquí vuelves a llamar a la función
```

Te sugiero recurrir a los [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) para que evites sobrecargar al servidor de peticiones.

Comment: Me ha funcionado bastante bien tu solución. Tendre en cuenta los web sockets para futuras funciones implementaciones.